# Need to have both p tag and br tag in tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

In tinyMCE editor, I need to have both p tag and br tag, which means p tag should wrap the br tag. While inspecting P tag wraps the BR tag `<p><br></p>` but in the code block of tinyMCE editor, it shows only p block, tried with `valid_elements:'*[*]`', not working.

[image: added br tag in the DOM]

[image: Without br tag]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this answer by myself via CSS, not in TinyMCE editor, We can add some height to the p tag if it is empty

```
p:empty{
height:5px;
}
```

to add space, if the br tag is not appending,

Found what the issue actually, When I removed the configuration `valid element: '*[*]'` , It works fine with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`